# Determine whether an image is PNG despite .BMP extension

Tags: c#, image

I want to check if images in a directory are of type png but with extension `.bmp`. The following determines whether it is a `.bmp` extension

```
 string x = Path.GetExtension(file);
```

From this we establish that its extension is `.bmp`. Now the problem comes in checking if it is in a png format. I am stuck on this part.

The reason why I am doing this is because I want to have my images transparent and .bmp images don't work so well with that.
Thank you!

Comment: See the accepted answer and first comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670546/determine-if-file-is-an-image

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston Even if the file is with an extension .bmp, the last 8 bits will be that answer that is in the other post? Interesting

Comment: @haysam the first 8 bytes, not the last 8 bits, but yes - the extension is just part of the filename, it's just convention that bitmaps are '.bmp' and PNGs are '.png'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read the first 4 bytes of the file:

```
byte[] b = new byte[4];
using (var fs = new FileStream(filename))
{
    fs.Read(b, 0, 4);
}
if (b.ToString().Contains("PNG"))
{
    // this is a png file
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can't always trust the filename extension. You should *always* check the file signature (first few magic bytes) to make sure the file is actually the type it claims to be.

Comment: -1 this is incorrect - answr below by @Andrew dh works

Answer (score 11):

The above answer is incorrect, the code should be:

```
var header = new byte[4];
using (var fs = new FileStream(filename))
{
    fs.Read(header, 0, 4);
}

var strHeader = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(header);
return strHeader.ToLower().EndsWith("png");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can check the file extension with this

```
 Byte[] imageBase64 = ....

 var encodedFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(imageBase64);
 return encodedFile.ToLower().StartsWith("?png", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take that I personally like since you don't have to check against strings (using the System.Drawing Library).

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filename))
{
    var fsImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
    if (fsImage.RawFormat == System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    {
       // Do something with Jpegs
    }
    else if (fsImage.RawFormat == System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    {
       // Do something with Pngs
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading the whole image is more expensive than reading the header.