# How to validate an image with wrong extension?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a text file stored as image (any extension) by renaming it in explorer.  I need to get the original type of file on uploading it using input(type=file).  Any possibilities?
Thanks in advance.

ASP.NET 2.0
Jquery 3.2.1

Comment: You have a .txt file stored as a .jpg/.bmp and you want to stream it in c# as a text file on upload?

Comment: I just want to detect whether it is a valid image file and to know its actual extension.  It could be done preferably in jquery (client side).  If not, then in server-side (vb.net) Thanks

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/670549/6048531

They check the headers and determine the file type.