# How can i read the content header of an image in windows phone using c#

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can i read the content type header information of an image file located in isolated in windows phone 8. I need to read the image extension information from its mime. Could anyone please guide me to a solution.

---

Using a mechanism something like posted in the thread helps.

[C# How can I test a file is a jpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772388/c-sharp-how-can-i-test-a-file-is-a-jpeg)

Comment: Do you mean the exif information?

Comment: I want to read the extension of the file from its header. If you write click on an image file and open it in text editor, it shows ******‰PNG***** or *******JFIF*****. Here * represents some garbage values which text editor does not understand. How can i do this in C#. I came across using system.drawing namespace to achieve it but thats not available in windows phone

Comment: Found the solution. The solution is to read the bytes and map them to there valid extensions. A solution to find jpeg is posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772388/c-sharp-how-can-i-test-a-file-is-a-jpeg