# How Do I Validate a JPEG Image in C# / .Net is not corrupted

Tags: c#, .net, image, gdi

I need to be able to validate if a JPEG image is valid and not corrupted.  This is not the same as [question 210650](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210650/validate-image-from-file-in-c) which just asks wants to validate that it is, in fact, a JPEG image.  Loading from Image with validation eg:

```
var testJpg = 
  Bitmap.FromStream(filename, useEmbeddedColorManagement, validateData);
```

will not throw an exception for clipped images.  Currently our solution is to try to open the file an external GD script and parse for any errors thrown from gdImageCreateFromJpeg.

```
gdImagePtr im;
im = gdImageCreateFromJpeg(testFile);
fclose(in);
```

But there has to be some .Net code somewhere that validates that a JPEG is not only valid, but contains the complete image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking [JPEG reference structure from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure), maybe you can look for EOI byte from the stream?

Answer (score 0):

There is the pnetlib that provides an [interop to jpeglib using c#](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidFACF234CEBEFEE89D4CB390FB122A0ECA4A20ED1.aspx), once you have that you can validate whatever you want.
You can try to use thier [JpegReader](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid47363CD43B2B3804B2609C76431E38B30A059AC1.aspx), maybe it will give you an error out of the box.