# Read image and determine if its corrupt C#

Tags: c#, image, corrupt

How do I determine if an image that I have as raw bytes is corrupted or not. Is there any opensource library that handles this issue for multiple formats in C#?

Thanks

Comment: What image formats do you need to support? If its just the basic 4 (bmp/png/gif/jpg) you could use the bitmap class and just attempt loading them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I Validate a JPEG Image in C# / .Net is not corrupted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173349/how-do-i-validate-a-jpeg-image-in-c-sharp-net-is-not-corrupted)

Comment: The Bitmap class can take bytes. Do you want to just check if its an image or do you want to check if its an image and a valid image?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to create a GDI+ Bitmap from the file. If creating the Bitmap object fails, then you could assume the image is corrupt. GDI+ supports a number of [file formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): BMP, GIF, JPEG, Exif, PNG, TIFF.

Something like this function should work:

```
public bool IsValidGDIPlusImage(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(filename))
        {
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You may be able to limit the `Exception` to just `ArgumentException`, but I would experiment with that first before making the switch.

**EDIT**
If you have a `byte[]`, then this should work:

```
public bool IsValidGDIPlusImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    try
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(ms))
            {
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. fine looks that is just what I needed! Thanks.

Comment: This should be used with care. It's important that you release the Bitmap created with *using*. Else it is quite possible that you'd get OutOfMemory Exception while checking large number of files because the system ran out of resources and not because image is corrupt.

Comment: @Kip9000 When the code within the using statement is complete, the bitmap will be disposed. No need to explicitly dispose of it.

Comment: See here for more info on using statements: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: I was emphasizing that using 'using' is important. Your code is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can look these links for taking an idea.
First one is here;
[Validate Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210650/validate-image-from-file-in-c-sharp)

And second one is here; [How to check corrupt TIFF images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621810/how-do-i-check-for-corrupt-tiff-images-in-c)

And sorry, I don't know any external library for this.