# Determine the real type of file vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file, upload

I have a asp.net vb.net app, with a upload file control, when i upload the file i can get the type of file the extension : .(extension),
But if the user change the extension  how i can get the real type of file?

Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should analyse the header contents of the uploaded data.

Comment: Does vb.net provide any object for this problem.
Thanx

Comment: there is no built in functionality in vb.net. I haven't found any libraries to do this automatically.

here how todo it manually with an mp3 file
http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=79

mp3 file format specification
http://www.mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html

others are out for checking images
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210650/validate-image-from-file-in-c