# How to determine if System.Drawing.Bitmap can open a file before trying to open?

Tags: c#, bitmap

We have some legacy code that has some... odd mannerisms. You can't really trust the file extension to know what kind of file it is. The big example is that the jpgs are actually tifs.

There may be other intricacies so I can't expect anything but the file's data itself to tell me if an image can be processed. I've wrapped it in a try/catch for now but I don't like using exceptions for flow control.

```
try
{
    using (Bitmap current = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(file))
    {
        // Use current
    }
}
catch
{
    // Must not be an image file
}
```

We can't change legacy code to make sense. Is there a better way than this to know that `file` is an image?

Answer (score 0):

It may sound dumb, but Bitmap opens files that are bmp or derivatives(png,jpeg, etc)

Could you try to check if the file extension has any of those extensions?

Comment: Ummm...I think the description of the problem states that this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably want to be using `Image.FromFile` instead of `Bitmap.FromFile`.

There really is no easy way to do what you're asking. `FromFile` will delegate to GDI+, and there's no way to know if GDI+ will like the file or not until you actually try to open it.

You could try to [write code to do some basic sanity check the headers of all the image types you want to support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9446045/288425). In the end though, it's still very possible that the header will be valid but the file itself will be corrupt. Also, you've added a new piece of complexity and possible vector for bugs in your code for processing image headers.

I would argue that this is in fact an exceptional case, and not an example of using exceptions for flow control. If a file that you think is an image turns out to not be, that's an exception.

Comment: Why use `Image.FromFile`? What's the difference?

Comment: `FromFile` is defined on `Image` and is not overridden by `Bitmap` — the only reason `Bitmap.FromFile` exists is because `Bitmap` is a subclass of `Image`. I suspect this is why examples from MSDN generally show `Image.FromFile` as well.

Comment: There is no difference.  Your explanation is actually reasoning not to care.